# PHP class instance not initialized (__construct does not work)

Tags: php

I've been trying to complete tutorial on laracasts lately, and after running this code somehow I don't get properly initialized $article1 (I'm running this on a fresh Homestead v6.1.0):

```
/**
 * @purpose
 *  To hold article data
 */
class Article {
    protected $time_created;
    protected $title;
    protected $text;
    protected $is_published = false;

    public function __contstuct($time_created, $title, $text) {
        $this->time_created = $time_created;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->text = $text;
    }
}

$article1 = new Article(time(), "this is the 1st article", "This is the long long text.");

var_dump($article1);
```

To be more specific, I get this as the result:
[image: To be more specific, I get this as a result]

Comment: What happens when you've debug one of those given properties? e.g (`var_dump($article1->title)`);

Comment: Those properties are protected, so I get this: 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access protected property Article::$title in /home/vagrant/Code/my-blog/index.php:23 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/vagrant/Code/my-blog/index.php on line 23

Comment: What happens if you correct this ? __contstuct

Comment: You have a typo. `__construct` is right.

Comment: fixed this typo, thanks! ;) __construct of course... however it does not solve the problem, I still see the NULLs..

Comment: Fixing this typo actually worked! thanks a lot, guys.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you wont see any property of your class because they are PROTECTED and you have 2 choices here:

1. change the PROTECTED to PUBLIC.
2. define getter for each of your properties or one for all of them due to your need.

   public function getProperties()
   {
    return [
            'time_created' => $this->time_created,
            'title'        => $this->title,
            'text'         => $this->text,
            'is_published' => $this->is_published
       ];
   }

Design your code as you wish.

Comment: Try this: `class Foo { protected $bar = 'baz'; } var_dump(new Foo);`, then you'll realise what you have written is bunkum.